# Last bytes are lost when sending from android client to python server

Tags: python, java, android, sockets, utf-8

So everything works fine, except when I have something that is not ascii sent over to the python server (That's my hypothesis).

Basically i sent a json String, part of which was:
`"Nova Nazaré - State of Mato Grosso, 78638-000, Brazil"`.

As you can see, there's an `'é'` char, which is not a standard ascii char.
So as I said i sent Json String, and due to the presence of the `'é'`, the last bracked `}` of the Json string was not sent and the data was corrupted. The same thing happens if i use for example, more than 1 non-ascii char, such as hebrew. More bytes are lost from the end of the String.

I wanted to ask how can I solve this... Since im using utf-8, not ascii. So i thought it should work.

Here's the sending function of my android client side (It's a part of a SocketTask class i created):

```
private void send(String sendingStr)
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new
                    OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // outputStreamWriter creating

            writer.write(sendingStr);
            writer.flush();

            Log.d("Result", "sent");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

And here's how I receive the data:

```
    while True:

        client_socket, client_address_port = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"{client_address_port} connected.")

        length_to_read = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH).decode('utf-8')
        activity_name = client_socket.recv(int(length_to_read)).decode('utf-8')

        print("Got: " + length_to_read + activity_name)

        if activity_name:

            length_to_read = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH).decode('utf-8')
            data_string = client_socket.recv(int(length_to_read)).decode('utf-8')

            print("Got: " + length_to_read + data_string)
```

Basically, already at the prints in the python sides, I see there are errors where the last bytes aren't read by the server or something.

And ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the header contains the length of the string in chars, rather than in bytes? Then, say your message is 100 chars long and contains 1 non-ascii character: it's 101 bytes long, but if the header states the length as 100, the Python code will only read the first 100 bytes and miss the last one.

Comment: Oh great heavens. This is an exquisite observation - it might actually be the error. I'll update in a jiffy.

Comment: That solved it! what a silly overlook by me. Much obliged!

Comment: @preno1221 Consider creating and accepting an answer (including an explanation) for your question. A question with an accepted answer is more helpful to the SO community than a resolution buried in the comments.

Comment: You mean I should write the answer by myself?

Comment: @preno1221 Yes. Write the answer yourself - there's nothing wrong with doing that at all, and it's much better than leaving the question unanswered. And accept your own answer as well. Also, as a separate matter, please note that when you want to direct a comment to a specific person for your question, include their username prefixed by an @ sign (as I have done for this comment) so that they are notified of the comment.